# How to download saved reports using Fortify Software Security Center REST API?

Tags: java, api, fortify

```
  I am trying to implement REST API for Fortify Software Security Center using Java. I am able to obtain
```

1)token by using following url

> http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/ssc/api/v1/auth/obtain_token

response for above URL as below

```
    {
      "data": {
        "token": "NDIxMjE0NjUtOGIwNy00ZjFiLWEzMTUtZjZkYTg0MWY1Zjgz",
        "creationDate": "2016-09-14T05:49:34.000+0000",
        "terminalDate": "2016-09-15T05:49:34.000+0000"
      },
      "responseCode": 200
    }
```

and 
2)get list of reports using following URL

> http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/ssc/api/v1/reports

response for above URL as below

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "note": "",
      "_href": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/ssc/api/v1/reports/17",
      "formatDefaultText": "PDF",
      "projects": [
        {
          "id": 16,
          "name": "Project 1",
          "versions": [
            {
              "id": 30,
              "name": "1.0",
              "developmentPhase": "New"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "authEntity": {
        "id": 2,
        "userName": "AAA",
        "firstName": "AAA",
        "lastName": "AAA"
      },
      "isPublished": false,
      "format": "PDF",
      "generationDate": "2016-08-03T10:56:46.000+0000",
      "statusDefaultText": "Processing Complete",
      "reportDefinitionId": null,
      "type": "ISSUE",
      "typeDefaultText": "Issue Reports",
      "inputReportParameters": null,
      "name": "Project 1",
      "id": 17,
      "status": "PROCESS_COMPLETE"
    },
    {
      "note": "",
      "_href": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/ssc/api/v1/reports/22",
      "formatDefaultText": "PDF",
      "projects": [
        {
          "id": 16,
          "name": "Project 2",
          "versions": [
            {
              "id": 30,
              "name": "1.0",
              "developmentPhase": "New"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "authEntity": {
        "id": 10,
        "userName": "BBB",
        "firstName": "BBB",
        "lastName": "BBB"
      },
      "isPublished": false,
      "format": "PDF",
      "generationDate": "2016-08-24T13:45:30.000+0000",
      "statusDefaultText": "Processing Complete",
      "reportDefinitionId": null,
      "type": "ISSUE",
      "typeDefaultText": "Issue Reports",
      "inputReportParameters": null,
      "name": "Project 2",
      "id": 22,
      "status": "PROCESS_COMPLETE"
    },
    {
      "note": "",
      "_href": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/ssc/api/v1/reports/41",
      "formatDefaultText": "PDF",
      "projects": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Project 3",
          "versions": [
            {
              "id": 3,
              "name": "1.0",
              "developmentPhase": "Active Development"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "authEntity": {
        "id": 10,
        "userName": "CCC",
        "firstName": "CCC",
        "lastName": "CCC"
      },
      "isPublished": false,
      "format": "PDF",
      "generationDate": "2016-08-25T16:56:22.000+0000",
      "statusDefaultText": "Processing Complete",
      "reportDefinitionId": null,
      "type": "ISSUE",
      "typeDefaultText": "Issue Reports",
      "inputReportParameters": null,
      "name": "Project 3",
      "id": 41,
      "status": "PROCESS_COMPLETE"
    },
    {
      "note": "",
      "_href": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/ssc/api/v1/reports/57",
      "formatDefaultText": "XLS",
      "projects": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Project 4",
          "versions": [
            {
              "id": 3,
              "name": "1.0",
              "developmentPhase": "Active Development"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "authEntity": {
        "id": 11,
        "userName": "DDD",
        "firstName": "DDD",
        "lastName": "DDD"
      },
      "isPublished": false,
      "format": "XLS",
      "generationDate": "2016-09-09T15:46:22.000+0000",
      "statusDefaultText": "Processing Complete",
      "reportDefinitionId": null,
      "type": "ISSUE",
      "typeDefaultText": "Issue Reports",
      "inputReportParameters": null,
      "name": "Project 4",
      "id": 57,
      "status": "PROCESS_COMPLETE"
    }
  ],
  "count": 4,
  "responseCode": 200,
  "links": {
    "last": {
      "href": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/ssc/api/v1/reports/?start=0"
    },
    "first": {
      "href": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/ssc/api/v1/reports/?start=0"
    }
  }
}
```

But I didn't find any end point URL to download the saved reports. Can you please help me to get the end point URL or provide reference API document for HP fortify Software Security Center.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is kind of an old post but just ran into the issue myself and found the solution.

First you have to request a file token as a HTTPPost:

`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/ssc/api/v1/fileTokens`

with:

```
{"fileTokenType": "REPORT_FILE"}
```

in the request body.

This will return a unique id that you will use to fetch your report.

Next you will make another get request like such:

`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/ssc/transfer/reportDownload.html?mat=[file_token]&id=[project_id]`

you will replace the [file_token] with the token returned from the above post and [project_id] with the project you want to download the report for.

so for example:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/ssc/transfer/reportDownload.html?mat=7e8d912e-2432-6496-3232-709b05513bf2&id=1
```

This will return the binary data that you can then save to a file. The file type is specified in the report data as "format"